# Trouble understanding recursion in finding if a binary tree is balanced

Tags: algorithm, recursion

```
int cntHeight(TreeNode *root) {
    if(root == NULL) return 0;
    int l = cntHeight(root->left);
    int r = cntHeight(root->right);
    if(l < 0 || r < 0 || abs(l-r) > 1) return -1;
    else  return max(l, r) + 1;
}

bool isBalanced(TreeNode *root) {
    return cntHeight(root) >= 0;
}
```

I have found this solution in C to check if a binary tree is balanced. However, I am having a very hard time visualizing how this algorithm works entirely. For that reason, there are two things I am uncertain about.

1. Does the algorithm recurse in the middle of the tree and not just the sides?
2. I noticed that only `max(1, r)` is called, don't we need to find the `min` as well?

Furthermore, how would you even go about developing an algorithm like this? I wouldn't know how to come up with a solution like this..

Comment: Visualizing? A binary tree is one parent node and up to two child trees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, it recurses the middle of the tree as well. It checks the left and right side of every node, which will naturally include the middle.
2. Why would you need the min? You're interested in the greatest depth = the height. Note that it's `max(l, r)` not `max(1, r)` (stupid Ls)
3. You develop it by starting small. Think about a tree consisting of a single node, what should that return? Then add another layer. And another. You will often find that the solution to one layer depends on the solution to the previous layer. That's where the recursion comes in. Then you have to think about what happens if the function calls itself; when will it stop calling itself? This is called the base case (in this case, `if(root == null)`). If it doesn't stop, you will get a **stack overflow**.

Answer (score 1):

The magic happens in the cntHeight function. It takes part of the tree as argument and returns 0 if that part is empty, -1 if it is unbalanced and its depth if it is balanced otherwise.

To do that it first gets the depth of both its subtrees (left and right) by calling itself. If one of those subtrees is unbalanced the whole tree is unbalanced so it returns -1 right away. If one of the subtrees is 2 deeper than the other, the tree is unbalanced as well, so it returns -1 (that’s what `abs(l-r) > 1` checks for)

In the last line the function calculates the depth of the passed tree. This is the depth of the deeper subtree (hence the `max`) + 1 for the root node.

I would say the main ingredient for developing an algorithm like this is experience. The more algorithms you have seen, the more of a feeling for the available methods you will get.